# Deployment Project not Removing Previous Project COM References

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, com, setup-project

I have a Microsoft Visual Studio Deployment Project that generates a basic setup.exe and appropriate MSI file. I leave the UpdateCode alone, but change the ProjectCode and Version on each build. I've also set the RemovePreviousVersions property to True. However, after I upgrade a machine, it seems as though any class flagged with COM does not become registered. I have to uninstall and reinstall the app for it to work. Any ideas why? This is done in VS 2010 targeting .NET 4. It's a COM-enabled WinForms app.

Comment: Erm, isn't the class already registered *before* you upgrade?

Comment: Yes. What seems to happen is that while the class is registered, it never unregisters and reregisters during an upgrade. So, any changes made to the class are not updated on the local box.